# Visual script editing software tool for creating game behavior logic

Tags: scripting, tools

Is there a visual script editing software tool in any game engine similar to [Visual3d](http://game-engine.visual3d.net/wiki/visual-script-editor-game-logic-and-behavior-diagrams) for  creating game behavior logic by non-programmers like designers?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is [kismet](http://udkc.info/index.php?title=Tutorials:Introduction_to_Kismet) in Unreal engine.